# How to show images in neovim

Tags: image, terminal, neovim

I use Warp Terminal (and sometimes iterm2). Is there any way to show images in them while using neovim? I tried searching for some plugins online but the only one i found was Hologram, which seems to be only for kitty.

[here's what the output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lhB1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [feh](https://feh.finalrewind.org/) to view image in terminal.

If you want to do this inside Neovim, just use `:!feh {file name}.png`